# Data Wrangling in Excel - Rearranging Columns and Rows

Tags: excel, pivot, transpose

I have a massive dataset in excel. I would like to rearrange the rows and columns.

Here's a snippet of the data, what it looks like and what I'd like it to look like under.

```
Area, Channel, Unit,  Year1, Year2, Year3, Year4
bel,  dc,      share, 25,    36,    56,    45   
bel,  dc,      avm,   23,    45,    65,    47,
bel,  dc,      ats,   45,    2,     3,     4,
bel,  tl,      share, 25,    36,    56,    45   
bel,  tl,      avm,   23,    45,    65,    47,
bel,  tl,      ats,   45,    2,     3,     4,
```

I'd like to switch Unit and the Years (Year1, Year2, Year3, Year4). To look like this

```
Area, Chennel, Year, Share, avm, ats
bel,  dc,      Year1, 25,    23,  45
bel,  dc,      Year2, 36,    45,  2
bel,  dc,      Year3, 56,    65,  3
bel,  dc,      Year4, 45,    47,  4
bel,  tl,      Year1, 25,    23,  45
bel,  tl,      Year2, 36,    45,  2
bel,  tl,      Year3, 56,    65,  3
bel,  tl,      Year4, 45,    47,  4
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: without using VBA. I think the Offset function might do the trick but Im still not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this sort of thing - I usually use index-match.

I do this sort of thing with index-match.

`=INDEX($D$2:$G$4,MATCH(D$7,$C$2:$C$4,0),MATCH($C8,$D$1:$G$1,0))`

First I build the spot where I am going to transpose the data:
[image]

Then I put in the proper formula:
[image]

Here's how it works:

In this usage `Index` takes three arguments:  A range of numbers, the row I want to grab from and the column I want to grab from.

The range never changes, so I lock that in with dollar signs (hitting f4 `INDEX( $D$2:$G$4`

The next argument is the row I want to grab from.  I use `match` to find it.  `Match(` takes three arguments also:  the value I want to find, the range I am going to find it in, and a `0` to let excel know that my range is not in order, and it needs to find an *exact* match.

So my index row is `MATCH(D$7,$C$2:$C$4,0)`:  *Find `"Year1"` in the range `$D$1 -> $G$1`.*  I used the dollar signs here to lock in rows and column so I can copy the formula to the whole table, and only the parts that need to change will.

Comment: This looks interesting, I'll run some tests and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: struggling to make this work when there is more than one channel. Ive added another channel to my example.

Comment: Keep the same basic structure, but now you need to adjust your row specification a little more. As long as _share, avm, & ats_ always come in the same order, that isn't too hard.  Just use match to search for the first occurrence of your channel label (`match($B8, $B2$b4,0)`) and add the result onto your row spec:  Your upper left formula will now be something like: `INDEX($D$2:$G$4,MATCH(D$7,$C$2:$C$4,0) + match($B8, $B2$b4,0) ,MATCH($C8,$D$1:$G$1,0))`  Your will be a little different because you have added rows onto your top table.