# Showing datatable as a visual

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I have some data which includes a list of tasks for 2 individuals.

[image]

I want to represent this data in the following format.

[image]

So that it looks like the below.

[image]

How can I achieve this with the use of formulas?

[EDIT]
I don't think this question is the same as 'Data Wrangling in Excel - Rearranging Columns and Rows' as mine is about reflecting schedules in a more gantt chart-esque like format, whereas the other question seems to be more about transposing data.

Comment: Mind sharing what method/formula you had tried/searched for this.. ? ( :

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data Wrangling in Excel - Rearranging Columns and Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652263/data-wrangling-in-excel-rearranging-columns-and-rows)

Comment: I don't think this question is the same as 'Data Wrangling in Excel - Rearranging Columns and Rows' as mine is about reflecting schedules in a more gantt chart-esque like format, whereas the other question seems to be more about transposing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you have your desired output on the same sheet or a new sheet, but I used a new sheet starting in cell `A1`.  The source datasheet is referred to as `S1` in the formulas.

#### Assumptions:

- `Column C` = Date Start
- `Column D` = Date End
- Persons' entries are grouped together (Person1, Person1, then Person2; never Person1, Person2, Person1)
- Person can't be assigned two different areas for the same timeframe (e.g., Person1 can't have A and B for a given month)
- Your desired dates are always the first of the month

#### Output/Formulas:

- `A1` is blank
- `A2`: `=INDEX('S1'!$A$1:$A$6,IFERROR(MATCH(A1,'S1'!$A$1:$A$6,0),1)+COUNTIF('S1'!$A$1:$A$6,A1))`
- `A3`: Formula copied down from `A2`
- `B1`: `=IF(A1<>"",EDATE(A1,1),MIN('S1'!$C$1:$D$6))`
- `C1` to `J1`: Formula copied from `B1`
- `B2`: =`INDEX('S1'!$B$1:$B$6,MATCH(1,INDEX(('S1'!$A$1:$A$6=$A2)*('S1'!$C$1:$C$6<=B$1)*('S1'!$D$1:$D$6>=B$1),0),0))`
- `B3` and `C2` to `J3`: Formula copied from `B2`

#### Explanations:

- **The `A2` formula:** Looks at where the previous Person entry first occurs (`MATCH` part), and counts how many entries it has (`COUNTIF` part) to determine the next Person entry in line (`INDEX` part).  The `IFERROR` portion is used to return the first Person entry, which is assumed to be on row 1.
- **The `B1` formula:** Adds one month to the previous date heading (`EDATE` part).  The very first date heading looks for the earliest date in your source data (`MIN` part).
- **The `B2` formula:** Uses a match with multiple criteria on your source data (Person entry must match the indicated person, start date must be before or on the date heading, and end date must be after or on the date heading).  The second `INDEX` creates an array of the combined criteria results (1 if true, 0 if false), and the `MATCH` returns which entry that is.  The first `INDEX` returns the task (A, B, or C).

Comment: Thank you. I had to make some changes, but it does work :)